# Retrieve content element field from within a plugin template?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, typo3-9.x

I am modifying the template of a plugin, and I want to retrieve a field from the content element.

Using `f:debug` I see the only data available is from the plugin itself, and none from the content element.

Is there any way I can perhaps insert the field I need in the plugin settings?

eg. something like:

```
plugin.tx_plugin.settings {
    contentUid = TEXT
    contentUid.field = uid
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way I can think of to do this is with a custom ViewHelper. Something like:

```php
namespace MyVendor\MyExtension\ViewHelpers;

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Configuration\ConfigurationManager;
use TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\Rendering\RenderingContextInterface;
use TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractViewHelper;

class ContentUidViewHelper extends AbstractViewHelper
{
    public static function renderStatic(array $arguments, \Closure $renderChildrenClosure, RenderingContextInterface $renderingContext)
    {
        $configurationManager = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConfigurationManager::class);
        return $configurationManager->getContentObject()->data['uid'];
    }
}
```

In your Fluid template:

```xml
<mynamespace:contentUid />
```

This will get the uid of the content element, but you can get any field this way. Just change the key of the `data` array to the field you need.

Comment: This is probably a stupid question, but can the vendor be any name I choose?

Comment: Yes. The namespace is meant to prevent problems with duplicate class names, so you should pick a vendor name that's unique for you. Often company or programmer names are used for this. TYPO3 extensions do need the namespace format to be `VendorName/ExtensionName` with the directory structure inside the `Classes` directory in your extension after that. So if this ViewHelper is in `EXT:site_template/Classes/ViewHelpers/ContentUrlViewHelper.php` the namespace should be `VendorName/SiteTemplate/ViewHelpers` and the class name should be `ContentUrlViewHelper`

Comment: Sorry I must be dense, because I keep getting an Unknown namespace error. I have `EXT:site_template/Classes/ViewHelpers/ContentFieldViewHelper.php` in it the namespace is `Test\SiteTemplate\ViewHelpers` and the class is `ContentFieldViewHelper`. Then in my template I put `{namespace cfvh=Test\SiteTemplate\ViewHelpers}` and `<cfvh:contentField />` is that right?

Comment: That does look correct. How are you installing your site template? Are you using composer?

Comment: Just uploading files, not using composer.

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled the extention, and it is working now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In the corresponding method (like the `listAction` or `showAction`) of the controller you can get the data of the content element in the following way:

```
$contentObject = $this->configurationManager->getContentObject();
$this->view->assign('contentObjectData', $contentObject->data);
```

As far as I know, you can't get to that data using typoscript, but I've never needed it anyway since I've been using the above code in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

`settings` do not have *stdWrap*-type per default, but only *string*. So you can not use cObjects as values.

For one (or a few) settings, you could do the *stdWrap*-processing in your method/class yourself:

```
$settingsAsTypoScriptArray = $this->objectManager->get(TypoScriptService::class)->convertPlainArrayToTypoScriptArray($this->settings);
$contentObj = $this->configurationManager->getContentObject();
if ($contentObj === null) {
  $contentObj = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ContentObjectRenderer::class);
}
// now override the values in the settings array with the processed value
$contentUid = (int)$contentObj->stdWrap($settingsAsTypoScriptArray['contentUid'], $settingsAsTypoScriptArray['contentUid.']);
```

If you wanna have many settings to be *stdWrap*ed, have a look into EXT:news. Georg implemented an interesting concept via [*useStdWrap*](https://docs.typo3.org/p/georgringer/news/9.3/en-us/Reference/TypoScript/GeneralSettings.html#usestdwrap) configuration.

Comment: I am creating a site package, and the plugin is a third party extention. So I don't think this will be something I can do?